# Hardness of multiplicative vs. additive approximation

Tags: approximation, matching

[Chlebik and Chlebikova](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0304397505008741) prove that the problem "maximum 3-dimensional matching" is NP-hard to approximate within a multiplicative factor of $95/94$.
This means that, unless $P=NP$, there is no polynomial-time algorithm that finds a 3-dimensional matching with at least $(94/95)\cdot OPT$ edges, where $OPT$ is the number of edges in a maximum matching.

Suppose we would like an *additive* approximation algorithm, that finds a 3-dimensional matching with at least $OPT-1$ edges. Is such algorithm theoretically possible (if $P\neq NP$)?

Comment: wouldn't we have $OPT-1\ge (94/95)\cdot OPT$ for large enough $OPT$?

Comment: @nirshahar If we have an additive approximation algorithm, and $OPT \geq 95$, then we also have a multiplicative approximation algorithm, since $OPT-1\geq 94/95(OPT)$. But what if $OPT < 95$?

Comment: but then there will be only $\sum_{k=1}^{OPT}{|T| \choose k}$ options for possible matchings $M\subseteq T$, and traversing all of them is polynomial (since $OPT<95$) So finding a good additive approximation will yield a good multiplicative approximation as well

Comment: Do you think this argument is correct?

Comment: @nirshahar it seems the following reduction should work.  (a) Check all possible matchings of size at most 95. This takes time $O(|T|^{95})$. (b) If there is no matching of size 95, then return the maximum matching found so far; its size is $OPT$. (c) Otherwise, $OPT\geq 95$. Run the additive approximation. It must return a matching of size at least $(94/95)\cdot OPT$.